# Is there any method to get get the Total utilisation of DataLake Store

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-lake

I would like to get the total utilisation of data lake store in python. Although im using  azure.datalake.store library. Im unable to achieve this.

the library contains several methods to get the info. Although, the parameters doesn't have any size value in it.

Is there any suitable method to get the metrics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but you can use [`Azure Monitor SDK for Python`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/monitor/azure-mgmt-monitor) for that purpose. For [`Data Lake Accounts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftdatalakestoreaccounts), one of the metrics available is `Total Storage` which should give you the total amount of data stored in a Data Lake account.

I believe the REST API operation is [`Metrics - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) and the equivalent SDK operation is [`list`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/monitor/azure-mgmt-monitor/azure/mgmt/monitor/v2018_01_01/operations/_metrics_operations.py).